# JAVA POST request and then redirect to it?

Tags: java, redirect, post

What I need to do is send POST request to specific URL with two parameters and when the request is sent, I need to redirect user to that link so that he would be able to access functionality.

So far, what I have managed to do from various examples is this:

```
    private void postRemoteAdvisoryLink() throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(KdrmApplicationContext.getRemoteAdvisoryUrlPath());
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        // For post only - start
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(("?auth=ssor&TransportKey=" + ssorTransportKey).getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    }
```

The problem is that now I get connection time out when trying to execute OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream(); line. Also, I still have no idea how to redirect user when request is completed.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your code you never specify which URL you are requesting.
To redirect the user to some other page, you have to use http code 301 or 302 in the http response to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Using the basic Java URL classes would require you to manually handle the details of HTTP protocol - it's better to use libraries like Apache Http Components, as they deal with the underlying protocols for you. Some examples including POST requests can be found [on their website](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Given the original question, the Timeout is likely related to host not responding or your Java application being unable to connect to given URL (due to no proxy configuration for example).

If you want to redirect a request based on the answer, you need to check the response headers and http status - if the status is 302, then there should be a header called Location, which will contain the URL you should make another request to.
Before getting an OutputStream, also make sure to set the Content-Length header (and ideally the Content-Type header as well).